# Loop through DAO Recordset

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

I have a database with more than 1000 records with similar data. I use Access.Form to enter values used for calculation and I want to make data updates, based on those calculations, in a table for each record so I can use it for reports.

I can't make this code loop through DAO.Recordset. I get the same data as for 1st record.

```
Dim MyDB As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Contacts")

rs.MoveFirst

Do Until rs.EOF
rs.Edit
Dim a1 As Double
Dim a2 As Double
Dim a3 As Double
Dim a4 As Double
Dim a5 As Double
Dim a6 As Double
Dim a7 As Double
Dim a8 As Double
Dim a9 As Double
Dim a10 As Double
Dim a11 As Double
Dim a12 As Double
Dim a13 As Double
Dim a14 As Double
Dim a15 As Double
Dim a16 As Double
Dim a17 As Double
Dim a18 As Double
Dim a19 As Double
Dim a20 As Double
Dim a21 As Double
Dim a22 As Double
Dim a23 As Double
Dim c1 As Date
Dim c2 As Date
Dim c3 As Date
Dim c4 As Date
Dim b1 As Date
Dim b2 As Date
Dim b3 As Double
Dim b4 As Double
Dim b5 As Double
Dim d1  As Date
Dim d2  As Date
Dim d3  As Date
Dim d4  As Date
Dim d5  As Date
Dim d6  As Date
Dim d7  As Double
Dim d8  As Double
Dim d9  As Double
Dim d10  As Double
d1 = Text541.Value
d2 = Text542.Value
d3 = [Datum_Ugovora]
d4 = [Anex_Datum_OD]
d5 = [Raskid_Ugovora]
d6 = [Odjava_Sa_Ino]
d7 = [Satnica_SRB]
d8 = [Broj_Sati_SRB]
d9 = [Satnica_EUR]
d10 = [Broj_Sati_INO]
If d1 >= d3 And d1 <= d5 Then 'ugovor OD
c1 = d1
ElseIf d1 < d3 And Month(d1) = Month(d3) Then
c1 = d3
Else
c1 = 0
End If
If d2 >= d3 And d2 <= d5 Then 'ugovor do
c2 = d2
ElseIf d2 > d5 And Month(d2) = Month(d5) Then
c2 = d5
Else
c2 = 0
End If
If d1 >= d4 And d1 <= d6 Then 'anex OD
c3 = d1
ElseIf d1 < d4 And Month(d1) = Month(d4) Then
c3 = d4
Else
c3 = 0
End If
If d2 >= d4 And d2 <= d6 Then 'anex do
c4 = d2
ElseIf d2 > d6 And Month(d2) = Month(d6) Then
c4 = d6
Else
c4 = 0
End If
If c1 <= c3 Then
b1 = c3
b3 = ISO_WorkdayDiff(c1, c3, True) + ISO_WorkdayDiff(c4, c2, True)
Else
b1 = c1
b3 = ISO_WorkdayDiff(c1, d2, True)
End If
If c4 <= c2 Then
b2 = c2
b4 = ISO_WorkdayDiff(c3, c4, True)
Else
b2 = c4
b4 = ISO_WorkdayDiff(c3, d2, True)
End If
b5 = ISO_WorkdayDiff(DateSerial(Year(b2), Month(b2), 1), DateSerial(Year(b2), Month(b2) + 1, 1), True)
a1 = Me.Text550.Value * 800 * b4 / b5
a2 = d7 * d8
a3 = d9 * d10
a4 = a3 * Text550.Value
a5 = Me.Text608.Value * b3 / b5
a6 = (a2 - a5 * Me.Text566.Value) / (1 - Me.Text566.Value - Me.Text573.Value - Me.Text575.Value - Me.Text570.Value)
a7 = (a6 - a5) * Me.Text566.Value
a8 = a6 * Me.Text570.Value
a9 = a6 * Me.Text575.Value
a10 = a6 * Me.Text573.Value
a11 = a6 * Me.Text589.Value
a12 = a6 * Me.Text591.Value
a13 = a6 * Me.Text593.Value
a14 = a6 + a6 * (Me.Text593.Value + Me.Text591.Value + Me.Text589.Value)
a15 = Me.Text833.Value * b4 / b5
a16 = (a1 - a15) * Me.Text566.Value
a17 = a1 * Me.Text570.Value
a18 = a1 * Me.Text575.Value
a19 = a1 * Me.Text573.Value
a20 = a1 * Me.Text589.Value
a21 = a1 * Me.Text591.Value
a22 = a1 * Me.Text593.Value
a23 = a1 + a1 * (Me.Text593.Value + Me.Text591.Value + Me.Text589.Value)
rs!Broj_dana_u_SRB = b3
rs!Broj_dana_u_INO = b4
rs!Obracun_Plate_OD = b1
rs!Obracun_Plate_DO = b2
rs!Ukp_Broj_Radnih_dana_u_mjes = b5
rs!Kurs = Me.Text550.Value
rs!Neto_Plata_SRB = a2
rs!Neto_Plata_INO = a3
rs!Neto_Plata_INO_RSD = a4
rs!Poresko_Oslobodjenje_SRB = a5
rs!Bruto_Plata_SRB = a6
rs!Poreska_stopa_SRB = a7
rs!Doprinosi_SRB_Zaposleni_PIO = a8
rs!Doprinosi_SRB_Zaposleni_Zdravstvo = a9
rs!Doprinosi_SRB_Zaposleni_NeZaposlenost = a10
rs!Doprinosi_SRB_Poslodavac_PIO = a11
rs!Doprinosi_SRB_Poslodavac_Zdravstvo = a12
rs!Doprinosi_SRB_Poslodavac_NeZaposlenost = a13
rs!Ukupni_troskovi_plate_SRB = a14
rs!Poresko_Oslobodjenje_INO = a15
rs!Bruto_Plata_INO = a1
rs!Poreska_stopa_INO = a16
rs!Doprinosi_INO_Zaposleni_PIO = a17
rs!Doprinosi_INO_Zaposleni_Zdravstvo = a18
rs!Doprinosi_INO_Zaposleni_NeZaposlenost = a19
rs!Doprinosi_INO_Poslodavac_PIO = a20
rs!Doprinosi_INO_Poslodavac_Zdravstvo = a21
rs!Doprinosi_INO_Poslodavac_NeZaposlenost = a22
rs!Ukupni_troskovi_plate_INO = a23

rs.Update
rs.MoveNext
Loop
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
```

SQL Code, same result, duplicated values in all rows

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE contacts SET [Broj_dana_u_SRB] = " & b3
 DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE contacts SET [Broj_dana_u_INO] = " & b4
 DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE contacts SET [Obracun_Plate_OD] = " & b1
 DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE contacts SET [Obracun_Plate_DO] = " & b2
 DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE contacts SET [Ukp_Broj_Radnih_dana_u_mjes] = " & b5
 DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE contacts SET [Kurs] = " & Me.Text550.Value
 DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE contacts SET [Neto_Plata_SRB] = " & a2
 DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE contacts SET [Neto_Plata_INO] = " & a3
 DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE contacts SET [Neto_Plata_INO_RSD] = " & a4
 DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE contacts SET [Poresko_Oslobodjenje_SRB] = " & a5
 DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE contacts SET [Bruto_Plata_SRB] = " & a6
 DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE contacts SET [Poreska_stopa_SRB] = " & a7
 DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE contacts SET [Doprinosi_SRB_Zaposleni_PIO] = " & a8
 DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE contacts SET [Doprinosi_SRB_Zaposleni_Zdravstvo] = " & a9
 DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE contacts SET [Doprinosi_SRB_Zaposleni_NeZaposlenost] = " & a10
 DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE contacts SET [Doprinosi_SRB_Poslodavac_PIO] = " & a11
 DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE contacts SET [Doprinosi_SRB_Poslodavac_Zdravstvo] = " & a12
 DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE contacts SET [Doprinosi_SRB_Poslodavac_NeZaposlenost] = " & a13
 DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE contacts SET [Ukupni_troskovi_plate_SRB] = " & a14
 DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE contacts SET [Poresko_Oslobodjenje_INO] = " & a15
 DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE contacts SET [Bruto_Plata_INO] = " & a1
 DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE contacts SET [Poreska_stopa_INO] = " & a16
 DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE contacts SET [Doprinosi_INO_Zaposleni_PIO] = " & a17
 DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE contacts SET [Doprinosi_INO_Zaposleni_Zdravstvo] = " & a18
 DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE contacts SET [Doprinosi_INO_Zaposleni_NeZaposlenost] = " & a19
 DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE contacts SET [Doprinosi_INO_Poslodavac_PIO] = " & a20
 DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE contacts SET [Doprinosi_INO_Poslodavac_Zdravstvo] = " & a21
 DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE contacts SET [Doprinosi_INO_Poslodavac_NeZaposlenost] = " & a22
 DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE contacts SET [Ukupni_troskovi_plate_INO] = " & a23
```

Comment: Would it be easier to write the SQL to do this based on the forms inputs?

Comment: I will try to write it

Comment: With SQL i got same results, duplicated data in all rows

Comment: This cannot work. You loop through the recordset, but the calculations don't use any data from it. So it always calculates the same values, which you write into all records. Take a step back and re-think your approach.

Comment: Also, code like this is atrocious: `a6 = (a2 - a5 * Me.Text566.Value) / (1 - Me.Text566.Value - Me.Text573.Value - Me.Text575.Value - Me.Text570.Value)` . Please use meaningful names for variables and form controls. Neither you nor anybody else will be able to figure out what is going on here in a few months.

Comment: Andre thanky you very much, i found problem
it was at the begining of a code, i dinnt make reference for variables in recordset

d1 = Text541.Value
d2 = Text542.Value
d3 = rs!Datum_Ugovora
d4 = rs!Anex_Datum_OD
d5 = rs!Raskid_Ugovora
d6 = rs!Odjava_Sa_Ino
d7 = rs!Satnica_SRB
d8 = rs!Broj_Sati_SRB
d9 = rs!Satnica_EUR
d10 = rs!Broj_Sati_INO

Comment: Bit late to the party - only saw the post as it was updated a few minutes ago.  I haven't read the top code as it's badly formatted and all those `d2<d1` type naming conventions make my eyes hurt - but you `DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE contacts SET [Broj_dana_u_SRB] = " & b3` code will duplicate the values through the whole field as you're only telling it to update that field - you need to add a `WHERE` clause to narrow it down. `UPDATE contacts SET Broj_dana_u_SRB = 100 WHERE Broj_dana_u_SRB=50` for example.

Answer (score 1):

I found solution for this problem

i didnt write variable reference in recordset

```
d1 = Text541.Value
d2 = Text542.Value
d3 = rs!Datum_Ugovora
d4 = rs!Anex_Datum_OD
d5 = rs!Raskid_Ugovora
d6 = rs!Odjava_Sa_Ino
d7 = rs!Satnica_SRB
d8 = rs!Broj_Sati_SRB
d9 = rs!Satnica_EUR
d10 = rs!Broj_Sati_INO
```

Comment: This makes much more sense. :)